# Create a socket with parameters in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm a newbie in networking, want to know how and why :

**Situation** : Want to open a socket to a server and listen. Documentation (you may find [here](https://dev.streamlabs.com/docs/socket-api)) proposes something in js, want to adopt a python solution.

Assume I have a socketToken available, then my python code is :

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=%s" % socketToken
s.connect((host, 443))
```

As you can imagine, got an error :

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I conclude that the address is wrong, but I don't know how to connect and set up my connection with the token. I can create the socket with only the server address, but I have no idea what I can send after that ...

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You connect to specific address; the `token` is part of the URL path, not the address.  2. You cannot connect to a https: site with a plain socket, it doesn't know how to do the SSL handshake.